# In SwiftUI how do I update a Published property inside ViewModel1 from ViewModel2?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Fairly new to SwiftUI and trying to figure out how to use `ViewModels`. Coming from `UIKit` I tend to like binding button presses to view model events, then apply the business logic and return a new value.

I am trying this in SwiftUI:

```
struct MainView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: MainViewModel
    @State private var isShowingBottomSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello \(viewModel.username)")
                .font(.title)

            Button("Show bottom sheet") {
                isShowingBottomSheet = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingBottomSheet) {
                let viewModel = SheetViewModel()
                viewModel.event.usernameUpdated
                    .assign(to: &$viewModel.username)

                SheetView(viewModel: viewModel)
                    .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.15), .medium])
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Initializers

    init(viewModel: MainViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

}
```

With the view model:

```
final class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {

    // MARK: - Properties

    @Published var username = "John"

}
```

And `SheetView`:

```
struct SheetView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: SheetViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Some Sheet")
                .font(.title)

            Button("Change Name") {
                viewModel.event.updateUsernameButtonTapped.send(())
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Initializers

    init(viewModel: SheetViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

}
```

And `SheetViewModel`:

```
final class SheetViewModel: ObservableObject {

    // MARK: - Events

    struct Event {
        let updateUsernameButtonTapped = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
        let usernameUpdated = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    }

    // MARK: - Properties

    let event = Event()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    // MARK: - Binding

    private func bindEvents() {
        event.updateUsernameButtonTapped
            .map { "Sam" }
            .sink { [weak self] name in
                self?.event.usernameUpdated.send(name)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

}
```

I am getting the error `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String>' to expected argument type 'Published<String>.Publisher'`. I want my `SheetViewModel` to update the value of `@Published var username` in the `MainViewModel`. How would I go about this?

Comment: You should use `@Binding` instead. Declare username as a Binding property in the sheet view, delete the sheet view model and anything related to it and then pass `$viewmodel.username` to the sheet instead.

Comment: Why would the sheet component share the same view model though? What if the sheet has its own isolated business logic?

Comment: You can of course have a view model for the business logic and still pass the data using Binding.

Comment: We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI, that's what the View struct is for. Related vars and logic can go in a custom `@State` struct with mutating func. If you really need a reference type, e.g. for some async logic, then you could use `@StateObject` but in your case there is no need for that and the new `task` modifier has removed the need in 99% of cases.

Answer (score 0):

We usually don't need view model objects in SwiftUI which has a design that benefits from value semantics, rather than the more error prone reference semantics of UIKit. If you want to move logic out of the View struct you can group related state vars and mutating funcs in their own struct, e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var config = SheetConfig()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                    Text(config.text)
                    Button(action: show) {
                        Text("Edit Text")
                    }
                }
        .sheet(isPresented: $config.isShowing,
               onDismiss: didDismiss) {
            TextField("Text", $config.text)
        }
        
    }

    func show() {
        config.show(initialText: "Hello")
    }
    
    func didDismiss() {
        // Handle the dismissing action.
    }
}

struct SheetConfig {
    var text = ""
    var isShowing = false
    
    mutating func show(initialText: String) {
        text = initialText
        isShowing = true
    }
}
```

If you want to persist/sync data, or use Combine then you will need to resort to the reference type version of state which is `@StateObject`. However if you use the new async/await and `.task` then it's possible to still not need it.

Comment: Why don't we use ViewModels? Apple use view models in their official documentation.

Comment: Because the view struct is already doing the job of a view model. SwiftUI diffs these structs and creates/updates the actual UIViews on screen. Yeh its annoying the docs have these mistakes, not all of Apple's teams fully understand SwiftUI yet.

Comment: There was a  SwiftUI Apple Q&A today: MVVM was a common architecture in the days of UIKit where by the data a view showed was taken from a separate viewModel class. Is this still applicable in SwiftUI or is the `struct` itself now considered the viewModel?

Comment: SwiftUI tries to be agnostic to the overall architecture of your app. Though, in a traditional viewModel sense, I wouldn’t advise thinking of Views (the struct itself) as view models. That could have consequences like making the view less reusable, and tying business logic to the lifetime of SwiftUI views, which would make handling business logic more difficult than it needs to be.
In short, we would not suggest using the View as the view model. But SwiftUI does provide the tools to implement a classic MVVM architecture (e.g. StateObjects, ObservedObjects)

Comment: Not saying I don't believe you, just curious on the various opinions

Comment: I've seen that Q&A answer and I believe it was by Nick Teissler, shame he is totally wrong. I recommend Luca Bernardi for SwiftUI data flow.